# if a useState holds an object, does setting it to an identical object trigger downstream dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

```
const [stuff, set_stuff] = useState{a: 1}


...

set_stuff({a: 1})
```

when `set_stuff({a: 1})` is run, will it trigger downstream dependencies that listen to `stuff`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they listen to `stuff`, yes.

If they listen to a property of `stuff` that's equal to the previous value at that property (like `a` and `1`), no. Example:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [stuff, setStuff] = React.useState({a: 1});
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Will trigger later because stuff changed');
  }, [stuff]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Will not trigger later because stuff.a did not change');
  }, [stuff.a]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setStuff({ a: 1 });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  return 'foo';
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**React does not do the deep comparison**

If you want to trigger on value change do like below

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Something');
  }, [stuff.a]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you listen the object `stuff`, it will trigger downstream dependencies because the two identical object is not really identical in computer. When you `set_stuff`, you just changed the value of `stuff` by a new address pointer.

```js
const stuffOne = {a: 1}
const stuffTwo = {a: 1}
console.log(stuffOne === stuffTwo) // false
```